# Is it possible to get list of Bluetooth printers in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

How to get list of Bluetooth printers in Android?
Following code returns all bluetooth devices:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
java.util.Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

Is it possible to select only printers from these devices?

UPDATE:
Device class of bluetooth class of my printer is 1664.
But I cannot find such constant in Android SDK.
Do all bluetooth printers have device class 1664?

Answer (score 16):

This question is rather old now, but I would like to share my own experience for anyone needing this information.

You can get minor device class (`getDeviceClass()`) and major (`getMajorDeviceClass()`) on `getBluetoothClass()` and check them against available class numbers. `1536` is a major class representing imaging devices, and printers are specified by `1664` as the minor device class.

You may also use this online device class calculator to generate the classes:

http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html

Comment: Oddly enough it's still not in the Android SDK.